# Derivative in Banach spaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces

Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuosly differentiable and $K$ a compact metric space.

Define $F:C(K,\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow C(K,\mathbb{R})$ as
$$f\mapsto \psi \circ f $$

> Calculate $DF(f)$ for every $f$ in $C(K,\mathbb{R}^d)$.

By definition we can think that $DF(f)(h)(x)=D\psi(f(x))h(x)$ and so we have to prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have

$$\displaystyle\frac{|\psi(f(x)+h(x))-\psi(f(x))-D\psi(f(x))h(x)|}{|h(x)|}<\epsilon$$

whenever $||h||<\delta$ for every $x\in K$ and some $\delta$.

Since $K$ is compact then $K'=f(K)$ is compact and then this problem is equivalent to finding a $\delta>0$ such that

$$\displaystyle\frac{|\psi(y+h)-\psi(y)-D\psi(y))h|}{|h|}<\epsilon$$

for every $y\in K'$ whenever $|h|<\delta$.

But, I don't know exactly how to show this. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\psi(y+h)-\psi(y)
=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}\psi(y+th)\,dt
=\int_0^1 D \psi(y+th)h\,dt, $$
and also $$D\psi(y)h=\int_0^1 D \psi(y)h\,dt. $$
Now use the uniform continuity of $D\psi$.

Comment: why do we have the first integral?

Comment: I added an extra step in the calculation. I did put it there in the first place; not at all sure how it got lost. Finger trouble in the editor, I guess.

Comment: We don't really need the compactness to prove this, the continuity of $D\psi$ is actually enough. Is not it? The compactness is just necessary to ensure that $C(K, \mathbb{R}^d)$ is Banach.

Comment: Your needed result is of the form $\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0\;\forall y\in K'\cdots$, which seems to me to require uniform continuity, which in turn requires compactness, since all you had to begin with is continuity.